# 301 Redirect /author/username/ to /profile/username/

Tags: redirect, author

I have changed the `/author/` slug to `/profile/` by adding the following code in the file `functions.php`:

```
function new_author_base() {
global $wp_rewrite;
$author_slug = 'profile';
$wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
}
add_action('init', 'new_author_base');
```

Since Google is crawling my author pages now I need to redirect the old `/author/` urls to the new `/profile/` ones in the `.htaccess`...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to 'your' section of the `.htaccess` file (so not in the WordPress section):

```
Redirect 301 /author http://yourdomain.com/profile
```

Comment: @drabello glad to be of help :-)